# How do I make that the list of combinations has a parameter of max 5 words out of the 7 words that I gave to the algorithm?

Tags: python, arrays, list, random, time

In this code I have 7 words and when I run the file I get all possible combinations with the same word count of the list but I want it to give me all combinations with the same list of words with a max word count of 5. Can you please help me out on this?

```
from typing import List
import time, random

def measure_time(func):
def wrapper_time(*args, **kwargs):
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
    res = func(*args, **kwargs)
    end_time = time.perf_counter()
    return res, end_time - start_time

return wrapper_time


class Solution:
def permute(self, nums: List[int], method: int = 1) -> List[List[int]]:
    perms = []
    perm = []
    if method == 1:
        _, time_perm = self._permute_recur(nums, 0, len(nums) - 1, perms)
    elif method == 2:
        _, time_perm = self._permute_recur_agian(nums, perm, perms)
        print(perm)
    return perms, time_perm

@measure_time
def _permute_recur(self, nums: List[int], l: int, r: int, perms: List[List[int]]):
    # base case
    if l == r:
        perms.append(nums.copy())

    for i in range(l, r + 1):
        nums[l], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[l]
        self._permute_recur(nums, l + 1, r , perms)
        nums[l], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[l]

@measure_time
def _permute_recur_agian(self, nums: List[int], perm: List[int], perms_list: List[List[int]]):
    """
    The idea is similar to nestedForLoops visualized as a recursion tree.
    """
    if nums:
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            # perm.append(nums[i])  mistake, perm will be filled with all nums's elements.
            # Method1 perm_copy = copy.deepcopy(perm)
            # Method2 add in the parameter list using + (not in place)
            # caveat: list.append is in-place , which is useful for operating on global element perms_list
            # Note that:
            # perms_list pass by reference. shallow copy
            # perm + [nums[i]] pass by value instead of reference.
            self._permute_recur_agian(nums[:i] + nums[i+1:], perm + [nums[i]], perms_list)
    else:
        # Arrive at the last loop, i.e. leaf of the recursion tree.
        perms_list.append(perm)
```

As you see here I have given the list array 7 words. But the problem is that when I run the file it gives me all combinations of the length of array.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
array = ["abandon ","ability ","able ","about ","above ","absent ","absorb "]
sol = Solution()
# perms, time_perm = sol.permute(array, 1)
perms2, time_perm2 = sol.permute(array, 2)
print(perms2)
# print(perms, perms2)
# print(time_perm, time_perm2)

#print(permutations)
file = open('crack.txt', 'w') # Open a file to receive output
for permutaion in perms2:
text = " ".join(list(permutaion))
print(text)
file.write(text)
file.write('\n')
```

Comment: combinations or permutations?

Comment: Permutations. Can you help me?

Comment: I can't understand anything from your question. you should remove all the useless code. state what you want to achieve (also with a minimal example, input and expected output). Most of your code is useless for the question, it's just confusing other people like me willing to answer

Comment: What code should I remove then?

Comment: Please focus on 1) rephrasing your question 2) providing examples (input and expected output). The code in my opinion is just useless here. Like who cares about the `measure_time` function for example? It's just not needed.

Comment: Its not useless. I just can't figure how to set a limit to the output of being max 5 words

Comment: so your question is: given a list of N words, find all permutations of M words from the previous list, where M < N?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need the [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) built-in function:

```
from itertools import permutations

result = list(permutations(array, 5))
```

Comment: And the array is a list that I define with the same words in the previous code?

Comment: @BrickWall Yes, it's as simple as that